# Proving the sequence $(x_n)$ ($n \in \mathbb N$) with $x_0$ $\in$ ($0$,$\frac{1}{2}$) and $x_{n+1}$=$f(\frac{1}{x_n})$ is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> Let $f:\mathbb R^*\to\mathbb R$ be $f(x)=\dfrac{e^\frac1x}{x^2}$. Prove that the sequence $(x_n)$ ($n\in\mathbb N$) with $$x_0\in\left(0,\frac12\right),\ x_{n+1}=f\left(\frac1{x_n}\right)$$ is bounded and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n=0$.

I think the problem can be solved working from the inequality $0\lt x_0 \lt \frac{1}{2}$ and doing that I realize that the upper bound of the terms shrinks and that should be "clear" but what would be a mathematically accepted proof?

Just to make sure I am no getting anything wrong here is my "calculations":
$0\lt x_0 \lt 1/2$
Raising terms to the power of -$1$:
$2\lt \frac{1}{x_0}\lt\infty$
Applying f to every term:
$0\lt x_1\lt f(2)$
Then doing the same thing again results:
$0\lt x_2\lt f\biggl(\frac{4}{e^{\frac{1}{2}}}\biggr)$
$\frac{4}{e^{\frac{1}{2}}} \gt 2$ and given that $f$ is decreasing for any $x \gt -1/2$ then ultimately the value of the upper bound is actually shrinking.

I am guessing this is not enough to prove the convergence of the sequence, right?

Comment: So $x_{n+1}=g(x_n)$ where $g(x)=x^2e^x$. For what values of $x$, $g(x)<x$ holds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's denote $g(x)=f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=x^2 e^x$.

We have to study the sequence
$$x_{n+1} = g(x_n)$$

where $x_0 \in (0,1/2)$.

You can prove that $g$ is strictly increasing on $[0,1/2)$, that $g(x) <x$ on $(0,1/2)$ and that the equation $g(x) = x$ has $0$ for unique solution on the interval $[0,1/2)$.

Hence for $x_0 \in (0,1/2)$, the sequence $(x_n)$ is strictly decreasing and bounded below by $0$. Therefore it converges. As $g$ is continuous, $(x_n)$ converges to a fix point of $g$, that is towards $0$.

Comment: You've helped me a lot. Just to be sure though, my logic was right but the answer wouldn't have been enough, right?

Comment: @RaduGabriel Yes, you started well but you're missing precise arguments to prove convergence.